# Use angular-material-data-table in angular2

Tags: angular

Can we use the angular-material-data-table from https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table inside an angular2 project?

Comment: Looking for the exact same answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. This is built only for angularJs doesn't work for angular 2 and above. Although there is similar table in progress for angular 2 and above https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/581